# Binding StaticResource after changing ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm new with WPF

I've got a simple `Style` to set `ForeGround` and `BackGround` for `TextBlock`

I'm using a MVVM approach with `oViewModel` that exposes two colors.
The text `Test Works` and `Test Works` works fine.
But the text `Test not work` dose not apply the colors. I assume it is because I change the `ItemsSource` of inner `ListBox`.

Why does the `StaticResource` not work in this case.

```
<Window x:Class="app_manager.FormScripts.FormScriptsJson"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:app_manager.FormScripts"
        xmlns:json="clr-namespace:CtrlJson.Viewer;assembly=CtrlJson"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance d:Type=local:CViewScriptsJson, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}, Path=oViewModel}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Name="_this"
        Title="Scripts Results Analysis" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="ToolWindow">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="StyleTxt" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding sColorFore}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding sColorBack}" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <DockPanel Background="{Binding sColorBack}">
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Style="{StaticResource StyleTxt}" Text="Test Works"/>

        <Grid x:Name="GirdRoot">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition MinHeight="450"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition MinHeight="50"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="250"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackPanel
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan ="3"
                Margin="3"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Style="{StaticResource StyleTxt}" Text="Test Works too"/>
                <ListBox 
                        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="LstDataJson" ItemsSource="{Binding oLstDataDay}"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=sDataDaySelected}"
                         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource StyleTxt}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Test not work" Style="{StaticResource StyleTxt}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `TextBox`es for `Test Works` and `Test Works Too` have their data context set to the view model that contains the `sColorFore` and `sColorBack` properties. That is why the `StyleTxt` can access it. However, the items in your `ListBox` have their data context set to the corresponsing data object in the `LstDataJson`, which does not contain the `sColorFore` and `sColorBack` properties, hence they cannot be resolved by the binding.

You can either add those properties to the items, too, or create a second style that uses a `RelativeSource` binding to access the data context of their parent `ListBox`, which has its data context set to the view model that contains your color properties. Set this style `StyleItemTxt` instead of `StyleTxt` in your data template.

```
<Style x:Key="StyleItemTxt" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=DataContext.sColorFore}"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=DataContext.sColorBack}"/>
</Style>
```

Another option is to remove the color properties completely from the view model and move them to XAML, e.g. in a resource dictionary, so they can be reused in your application. This approach is favorable in general, since it separates view concerns from your business logic and data.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
But if I move the color in a XAML ressource they never can be dynamic change.
In my case the color depends of C# code.